# Error loading large JSON file into PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have an issue with a PowerShell script I am working on. What the script does is fetch a large amount of JSON from an API endpoint and append it to a file in increments of 100 results.

The file then needs to be read out and some of the JSON keys retrieved, but the file load is failing.

```
$jsonserial = New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = 104857600


$jsonFileName = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\a_big_json_file")
$jsonTree = $jsonserial.DeserializerObject($jsonFileName)
ConvertTo-Json $jsontree
$J = $jsontree

foreach ($line in $J) {
    echo $line."resource".entity | Where-Object {$_.buildpack -ne $null} | Select-Object name,buildpack
}
```

The error I get from PowerShell is:

> At C:\TEMP\software\get_buildpacks.ps1:39 char:1
>   + $jsonTree = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($jsonFileName)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Can anyone spot the issue? I am banging my head on the wall.

Comment: What is your `<Type>` that the JSON is structured like?  See [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm), for some visibility on why simply feeding it a string, may not work for you.  _(Although, we'd need to see the JSON and sample data to truly know)_

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864(v=vs.110).aspx, the following are possible causes of that exception: The length of input exceeds the value of MaxJsonLength. -or- The recursion limit defined by RecursionLimit was exceeded. -or- input contains an unexpected character sequence. -or- input is a dictionary type and a non-string key value was encountered. -or- input includes member definitions that are not available on the target type.

Comment: [CloudFoundry API docs](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/229/apps/list_all_apps.html) has an example of the JSON that would be coming out. I cannot post the actual JSON for company policy reasons.

The input is taken as JSON and run through converto-json anyway, just to make sure that it has passed powershells sniff test for valid json. Why would it then be invalid in the deserializerobject?

Comment: Why are you not using `Get-Content giantFile | ConvertFrom-Json` instead of mixing .NET and Powershell?

Comment: It looks like it is an issue with the JSON format of the file.  But it is hard to say without seeing a sample.  When you say you 'append' the JSON to the file how are you doing that?  Are you appending it in such a way as to ensure that content of the file, in its entirety, is still valid JSON?  Or do you just have a list of JSON strings, one after the other, each of which may be valid on their own, but when taken together they result in an invalid JSON string?